# How to enable light mode on my whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to programming and stackflow, but I have made a dark page that I want to enable light mode that works on every page

But whenever I try the Light mode it changes only the color of the body, and the 'p' text in the body.

How do I also make changes to example: class="row" or the whole page? Since i already have a code, i wish not to change everything to fit in light mode, but to implement what i have in some sort of code.

My idea was to add:
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
in my javascript, but it did not make a difference.

```js
function darkmode() {
    const wasDarkmode = localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === 'true';
    localStorage.setItem('darkmode', !wasDarkmode);
    const element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle('dark-mode', !wasDarkmode);
  }

  function onload() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode', localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === 'true');
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 1024px 300px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: auto;
  padding: 100px;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: #886750;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

 <body onload="onload()">
    
    <button class="nav-item">
      <a role="button" onclick="darkmode()">Klikk for lys modus</a>
    </button>
    
    <p>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut laborboris nisi ut aleur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">

        <h2>Information</h2>
        <h3>Information</h3>

        <br>

        <h2>Information</h2>
        <h3>Information</h3>

      </div>

      <div class="column">

        <h2>Information</h2>
        <h3>Information</h3>
    
        <br>

        <h2>Information</h2>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./js/darkmode.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Kevin Powell has a great [Dark Mode JavaScript toggle using localStorage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wodWDIdV9BY) tutorial that you can use for reference

Comment: Thanks! Looks like he already had this in mind when making the code, i would like to implement my curent code and make it work with light mode.

Answer (score -1):

A good approach is to define the styles for the default theme (e.g. "dark mode") and then start to override single styles.

In your example there are a couple of `background-color` and `color`  properties set to the same value - keep in mind that many style properties are inherited by child nodes, e.g. `color` and `background-color`.

If you want to have white text on a black background for all elements in "dark mode", but black text on white background in "light mode", then it is sufficient to define `background-color` and `color` for the `body` element:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /* other styles here */
}

body.light-mode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

The styles of class `light-mode` will be *added* to the `body` styles when you add the `light-mode` class to the `body` element, i.e. only `background-color` and `color` will be overridden.

For all other elements it's the same.

I have removed all `background-color` and `color` definitions from the CSS and added overrides for the "light theme" at the end:

```js
let darkMode = true;

function darkmode() {
    const wasDarkmode = darkMode; // localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === 'true';
    darkMode = !darkMode; // localStorage.setItem('darkmode', !wasDarkmode);
    const element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle('light-mode', wasDarkmode);
  }

  function onload() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('light-mode', !darkMode); // localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === 'true');
  }
```

```css
/* Default theme first */
body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 1024px 300px;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: auto;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: #886750;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-item {
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px #808080;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
}

/* Overrides for light mode style for body tag - will cascade */
body.light-mode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

/* Override style for "headline 2" in "light mode" */
.light-mode h2 {
  color: lightblue;
}

.light-mode .nav-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

 <body onload="onload()">
    
    <button class="nav-item">
      <a role="button" onclick="darkmode()">Klikk for lys modus</a>
    </button>
    
    <p>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut laborboris nisi ut aleur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">

        <h2>Information</h2>
        <h3>Information</h3>

        <br>

        <h2>Information</h2>
        <h3>Information</h3>

      </div>

      <div class="column">

        <h2>Information</h2>
        <h3>Information</h3>
    
        <br>

        <h2>Information</h2>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./js/darkmode.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you have som ideas for changing how the button looks? If i add .nav-item in css and try to style it, it does not seem to apply?

Comment: Sure. I edited the code in the answer above. Have a look at the CSS at the bottom :)